# Horario de entrada y salida en script de SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Buen día.

Como bien dice el título, ¿cómo podría expresar en una tabla un horario de trabajo de una empresa?

El enunciado dice:

> En una EMPRESA trabajan EMPLEADOS los cuales tienen un HORARIO de trabajo

Según lo que entendí, existen tres tablas, EMPRESA, EMPLEADOS y HORARIO, entonces, la tabla que formulé para el horario es la siguente

```
CREATE TABLE horario
(
entrada_salida_pk TIME PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Creo que es algo demasiado simplón y jamás había hecho una tabla de este tipo.

Agradezco de antemano vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Esta podria ser una opcion:
Id_Empleado: LLave foranea que relaciona la tabla empleado con la tabla horario
Hora_entrada: Hora de entrada del empleado
Hora_salida: Hora de salida del empleado

```
CREATE TABLE horario(
Id_Empleado int PRIMARY KEY,
Hora_entrada TIME,
Hora_salida TIME,
);
```

Y pueden haber mas datos, pero eso depende de lo que necesites...

Answer (score 1):

Consideremos lo siguiente:

- Los horarios registrados servirán para hacer cálculos con ellos
- Deberás almacenar en formato de *tiempo* tanto la entrada como la salida
- Deberás almacenar el `id` de quién autorizó este horario
- Cada horario debe tener un *status* para saber si sigue o no vigente
- Importante, la tabla horarios no es para almacenar la asistencia del empleado, de ahí solo consultamos el horario asignado
- Cuando des de alta a un empleado le registras como llave foránea el horario asignado
- En la tabla donde registres la asistencia guardas el id del empleado para referenciarlo y posterior la hora de entrada y salida